# Save list of table of numbers from Python into format easily readable by Mathematica?

Tags: python-2.7, wolfram-mathematica

I am running a simulation in Python. The simulation's results are summarized in a list of number matrices. Is there a nice export format I can use to write this list, so that later I can read the file in Mathematica easily, and Mathematica will recognize it as a list of matrices automatically?

Comment: How about HDF5 files?

Comment: from what you have supplied I'd also suggest HDF5, which fits your use case (many medium sized numeric matrices) perfectly. HDF5 is very well supported by python [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) and can be imported to Mathematica (I never have had any problems with simple datasets containing numeric arrays). Mathematica doesn't import hdf5 files very efficiently, but I'd still expect it to be much faster than any textual format and reading only particular matrices from such a single file storing many of those matrices will also work well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on how large your matrices are and whether speed or memory are a concern for you. The most simple solution is to create a plain-text *Mathematica* expression by yourself. Just iterate through your matrices and create a list of them in Mathematica formate. This boils down to writing braces and numbers in a file

```
{mat1, mat2, ...}
```

where `mat1`, etc are themselves lists of lists of numbers.

#### Update 1

If you want a standardized format, then you could look what you can easily [import into *Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalDataFormats.html). One thing that hits the eye (after it was hit by MTX, which obviously doesn't work) is the [MAT format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html). A quick search seems to indicate, that you can [write those files with Python](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html#matlab-files).

#### Update 2

Regarding your comment

> Pythonica looks nice. Regrettably, I am running the Python simulations on a cluster that does not have Mathematica installed. I am using Mathematica in my personal PC for post-processing.

OK, but the package is not even 500 lines of code. Why don't you skim over it and just take out what you need: Code that transforms arbitrary Python lists to *Mathematica* code

```
_id_to_mathematica = lambda x: str(x)


def _float_to_mathematica(x):
    return ("%e" % x).replace('e', '*10^')


def _complex_to_mathematica(z):
    return 'Complex' + ('[%e,%e]' % (z.real, z.imag)).replace('e', '*10^')


def _str_to_mathematica(s):
    return '\"%s\"' % s


def _iter_to_mathematica(xs):
    s = '{'
    for x in xs:
        s += _python_mathematica[type(x)](x)
        s += ','
    s = s[:-1]
    s += '}'
    return s


_python_mathematica = {bool: _id_to_mathematica,
                       type(None): _id_to_mathematica,
                       int: _id_to_mathematica,
                       float: _float_to_mathematica,
                       long: _id_to_mathematica,
                       complex: _complex_to_mathematica,
                       iter: _iter_to_mathematica,
                       list: _iter_to_mathematica,
                       set: _iter_to_mathematica,
                       xrange: _iter_to_mathematica,
                       str: _str_to_mathematica,
                       tuple: _iter_to_mathematica,
                       frozenset: _iter_to_mathematica}

l = [[1, 2, 3], 1, [1, 5, [7, 3, 7, 8]]]
print(_iter_to_mathematica(l))
```

The output is a string

```
{{1,2,3},1,{1,5,{7,3,7,8}}}
```

that you can directly save into a file and load it into *Mathematica* using `Get`.

Comment: I tried the `MTX` format. I get an error with multi-dimensional arrays. Seems to work only with 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @becko I haven't tried it, but you might want to look into writing MATLAB files. At least I have tested, that *Mathematica* can read lists of matrices :-)

Comment: However (and I know this isn't in the scope of the original question), ideally I would like a format that allowed me to read/write arbitrarily nested lists of lists ... of lists of numbers. `.mat` has the limitation that it won't understand a heterogenously sized nested list, like `[[2,3,4], [2,3], [2,2,[4,5]]]`.

Comment: Have you [seen this](https://github.com/bjedwards/pythonica)? Wouldn't it be easy to just load this package and call the Mathematica function `Export` with it to write your Python result directly as Mathematica mx format?

Comment: `Pythonica` looks nice. Regrettably, I am running the Python simulations on a cluster that does not have Mathematica installed. I am using Mathematica in my personal PC for post-processing.

Answer (score 1):

How big are the matrices?

If they are not too large, the JSON format will work well.  I have used this, it is easy to work with both in Python and Mathematica.

If they are large, I would try HDF5.  I have no experience with writing this from Python, but I know that it can store multiple datasets, thus it can store multiple matrices of different sizes.

Comment: Can you post some examples? How can I use the JSON format to do this?

Comment: Each matrix is not very large, say `200x200`, but the list of matrices contains many matrices. So the total data bulk that gets stored in a file can be huge.